# how to update perl on MacOS use command line?

Tags: perl

I have perl 5.16.2, and I want to update it to 5.18.x.

How to install the last version perl by terminal?

I already have HomeBrew, thanks!

Comment: you should not attempt to upgrade the built-in perl used by OS X. However, you could install an alternative perl alongside the system perl for your own use. Check out the [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) tool which helps you compile a perl of your own in your user directory – a solution [recommended by homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Gems,-Eggs-and-Perl-Modules#avoiding-sudo-altogether-for-perl) in their wiki.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved the problem by following your recommendation.